# Display ruby messages in a browser via a buffer

Tags: ruby, sinatra, buffer, stdout

I have a list of processes that display within my terminal perfectly but I want to modify the class so that the messages are not only displayed to the STDOUT channel but also written to a buffer.

I know I have to add a Sinatra method to the end of the file so that the buffer is displayed in a browser.

My code looks something like this at the moment (as you can see, I have tried to begin implementing the buffer but I am having trouble continuing from here):

```
require 'Sinatra'
$buffer = "buffer"

module ImpossibleMachine
    @process = []
    g = Game.new(STDOUT)

    g.start
            @process[0] = g.action_1(1)
            @process[1] = g.action_2(@process[0])
            @process[2] = g.action_3(@process[1])
    g.finish
end

# Sinatra route:

    get '/' do
        # missing sinatra code
    end
```

Comment: I really do not understand what you try to achieve with your global `$buffer` variable (which generally is a bad idea). Assigning it to your local `g` will just overwrite your reference to the `Game` object you just created and the `#start` method will be called on the `"buffer"` String which will not understand it. Why are you trying to store anything in a global String?

Comment: As it reads in the code, I didn't know that assigning it to the local    g would overwrite my reference to the 'Game'. So now I can get rid of that. However I still require the global '$buffer' variable. How do I modify the class so that it is written to a buffer?

Comment: Strings in ruby are mutable, so you may use the `+=` or `<<` to append to them in a reasonably transparent manner. That still does not answer the question what you would like to *do* with your `$buffer`. Of course you might just output it in your `get`, but that will hardly be the point.

Comment: Yes, that's simply what I want to do, just display the output via the Sinatra route. I know that may seem simple but I am very new to ruby & Sinatra.

Comment: If your `Game` class outputs to the `$buffer` you can just return its contents in your `get '/' do` or pass it via `stream` as @UriAgassi has proposed. Try it out.

Comment: The use of `$buffer` is code smell. Rarely should you need to use a global variable in Ruby, and you should avoid them until you really understand when they are appropriate. Beyond that, the way you're using the module is questionable; I'd recommend getting rid of it and simplifying. Look at the Sinatra tutorial and follow its lead more closely.

Comment: samgbelton, since you're a newer member to SO, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Thanks @iain, still getting to grips with this...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is [streaming](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/streaming.html):

> ```
> get '/' do
>   stream do |out|
>     out.puts "Hello World!", "How are you?"
>     out.write "Written #{out.pos} bytes so far!\n"
>     out.putc(65) unless out.closed?
>     out.flush
>   end
> end
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `Game` module is all about, but aside from that, you could wrap `warn` and `get` in a [DSL extension](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#extending-the-dsl-class-context-with-sinatraregister), e.g.

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module Buffer
    def get_with_buffer( path, &block )
      get path do
        @outputs ||= []
        block.call(@outputs)
        @outputs.each do |o|
          warn o
        end
        @outputs.join("\n")
      end
    end
  end
  register Buffer
end


app = Sinatra.new do
  register Sinatra::Buffer
  get_with_buffer "/" do |outputs|
    outputs << "First"
    outputs << "Second"
    outputs << "Third"
  end
end

app.run!
```